# Link to question being redirected

Tags: support

I had a look at this question:
[Advanced books on UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/advanced-books-on-ux)

and the link to intro books from that question links to:
http://uxexchange.com/questions/66/what-book-would-you-recommend-as-a-decent-intro-to-ux-aimed-at-non-practitioner

which ends up being redirected to:
[Is using the alt-attribute for text-as-graphics ok?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63/is-using-the-alt-attribute-for-text-as-graphics-ok/66#66)

When really it should be:
[What book would you recommend as a decent 'intro to UX' aimed at non-practitioners?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/what-book-would-you-recommend-as-a-decent-intro-to-ux-aimed-at-non-practitioner)

While the question could just be edited, I thought I should report it as it seems like it could be a bug. Why would it redirect to a random question? And why would they stuff the link up the like that initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a separate site called UXExchange.com built on an earlier iteration of Stack Exchange. A few months ago, questions from that site were merged into this one. The migration script didn't clean up the old links, so we've had to do so manually.

Thanks for pointing out the error. Go ahead and edit the question if you don't mind.

Comment: Is there a statute of limitations on making these updates?  I found a similar broken link on a question that hasn't been touched in 8 months.  Is it better to bump an aged question or leave in a bad link?

Comment: @Karen Definitely better to edit the question and fix the broken link. The majority of people hitting the home page today have probably never seen that old question, so bumping is actually a good thing. Thanks!